# Creating a cage for baking for a mesh that has a gap in it

Tags: mesh, texture-baking, normals, baking, normal-map

I know the concept of creating a cage by just copying the low poly mesh and inflating without changing anything else in terms of vertices etc. However, my mesh as shown has an inset and backwards extrusion which the cage doesn't cover even when scaled. Should I just manage with the ray distance even though it does not bake a perfect normal map or is there a way to fix this cage to encompass it all?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The details aren't massive but its on both edges of the mesh mainly.

[image]

Comment: Hi.The mesh seems to be pretty low poly - what do you want to bake and why?

Comment: Hello! what Im trying to do is bake the edges of this hammer as I sculpted with the cloud brush to implement dents but because my Laptop has slowed down so much. I decided to leave it as is and just go with what I made. I'm just still learning anyhow so wouldn't bother me how much detail is on it.

Comment: It's still hard to understand what you want to do. One usually needs to bake high resolution detail from high resolution mesh to a texture intended to be used on a low resolution mesh. It would explain a lot if you added screenshots of the high resolution mesh you want to bake and the low resolution version, that you want to bake to. It seems you only shared the images of the low resolution mesh so it is hard to understand where your problem is only looking at the information provided.

Comment: I've added the last pic just to show the small amount of sculpting details from the high poly.